# volatile example (that in JLS8/8.3.1.4 volatile Fields) not work?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, jls

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4

Java Language Specification 8/8.3.1.4 volatile Fields

[volatile example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zwo9k.png)

**Question:**

In the example of volatile, I add synchronized keyword to method `two()` to avoid executing `one()` during method `two()`.

But I still noticed `j` is larger than `i`: why ?

**Note:**

I use Java HotSpot 1.8.0_112.

```
If you can not noticed j is larger than i, please set testVolatile()/num to a larger number.
```

My demo:

```
public class VolatileDemo {

    static volatile int i = 0, j = 0;

    static void one() {
        i++;
        j++;
    }

    static synchronized void two() {
        if (i != j)
            System.out.println("i=" + i + " j=" + j);
    }

    static void testVolatile() {
        int num = 5000;
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    one();
                }
            }).start();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    two();
                }
            }).start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testVolatile();
    }
}
```

**My result:**

i=4996 j=4998

i=4998 j=5000

i=4998 j=5000

....

Comment: Both methods have to have the synchronized keyword to prevent simultaneous execution.

Comment: Thanks, I know, this is one of the approaches,  the Java provides a second mechanism, volatile fields, that is more convenient than locking for some purposes, I just want to know the usage of volatile.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible and it's described in the link you mentioned. It's at the end of the paragraph.

> It is possible, however, that any given invocation of method two might observe a value for j that is much greater than the value observed for i, because method one might be executed many times between the moment when method two fetches the value of i and the moment when method two fetches the value of j.

So two() method reads i and then j with the exact order as in your code. But there are a cople of one() method calls between that reads which gives the result of (4998, 5000)

Comment: Thanks,  I have noticed this. So in my demo code, I added synchronized keyword to method two(), so method one() should not execute during two();

Comment: @Zenna you have two synchronize them *both*